# Facing error after removing .php exetension

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess code after remove .php extension. I'm facing this error

> **Bad Request** Your browser sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

```
 DirectorySlash On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]
    # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,NC]
```

EDIT:

.htaccess is located inside the root directory.

The original URL is this: cloud9cumulus.com/shieldpayments/view/login.php

Comment: what is your original url please provide your current rules typical to understand.

Comment: https://www.cloud9cumulus.com/shieldpayments/view/tasks.php this is the url and

Comment: and in which folder you have your htaccess?

Comment: the code is too long  that's why i am not able to put it here

Comment: it is in main root folder

Comment: Improved quality of question and added info based on the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution of problem finally get and here it is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shieldpayments/view/([\w-]+)$ shieldpayments/view/$1.php [L]
```

This rule is enough to remove your .php extension for your current url, and remove other rule related to this before trying.